# Can Love Hormones be used to control Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie,

> Hulk turned back into Banner after feeling Natasha (girls found that too emotional, too). It looks to me as Love Hormones in action to kill the anger.

Can this fact be exploited to contain Hulk? Can we shoot Hulk with needles filled with Love Hormones to convert Hulk back into Banner (and, do it whenever necessary)? Has this thing been happened in the comics?

Comment: "Love and Anger can't exist together" - you aren't married, are you ?

Comment: The opposite of love is indifference, not anger.

Comment: @JoeL I never said it's opposite. I said it's anti.

Comment: @Eike I am not talking about philosophical love. When she drags you on the bed, do you remain angry?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 as far as my blood pressure, pulse rate, adrenaline and general hormone status etc. is concerned you would be really hard pressed to find a difference. Insofar I think arousal should send the Hulk of the rails rather than calm him down.

Comment: @Eike Then, what really happened when he touched Natasha? Maybe, that could be answer..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I'll concede that the idea that love conquers everything is rampant in fiction and might work in a comic book - but for reasons of storytelling, not because it makes any sense biologically (on the other hand we a discussing green gamma ray monsters, so perhaps I should abandon that train of tought right now).

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 : LOL "Love Hormones". I swear SS, sometimes you ask the best questions!

Comment: Do you mean pheromones?

Answer (score 5):

The image they have painted of the Hulk in the MCU is a very reactive creature of low intellect.

In Avengers, Hulk was able to stand his ground with the Avengers and take limited direction from Captain America. If however, the Hulk is provoked he becomes wild and uncontrollable.

Similarly, in Age of Ultron,

> Banner is able to unleash the Hulk during a 'Code Green'. But in contrast is set-off and becomes enraged before the fight with the Hulkbuster.

While anger is what makes the Hulk strong, its isn't the only part of his persona. During the parts you are talking about:

> Natasha approaches the Hulk with her hands up and speaks in a soft tone, because the Hulk is very much like a wild uncontrollable animal and says a phrase and touches the Hulk in a very specific way.

This seems to imply the Hulk isn't controlled by 'love' but by a very rehearsed hypnotic suggestion.

---

In addendum, its worth looking at why its Natasha who is doing the hypnotic suggestion and none of the others.

- Tony Stark - is afraid of the Hulk even in his armor, and is too brash and reactive himself, so I doubt he'll go up unarmed to calm the Hulk
- Hawkeye - is very self focused and likes to keep a distance as Selvig pointed out in the introduction of *The Avengers*, not only that he also:

> has a family to worry about, unlike Natasha

- Thor - unlikely, as Hulk and Thor have come to blows on many occasions, so the would-be-king of Asgard would probably not calm him down
- Captain America - maybe the Cap could do it, he is calm under pressure, although unlike Natasha he's very much a pugilist and probably doesn't have Natashas expertise in psychology.

So, the logical choice is Natasha - she's smart, calm under pressure and the only one brave enough to face the Hulk. Keep in mind in her opening scene in the Avengers she was chained to a chair and dangling over a hole, completely unafraid. Plus, shes 'fought' the Hulk, and knows what to look for in a spate of rage and what might set Banner off. If there was an element of psychological control at play, Nat is probably the only Avenger qualified to control the Hulk.

Lastly, I think you have your premise back to front:

> Natasha isn't able to control the Hulk because Banner loves her, considering how much Banner despises the Hulk (and vice-versa), Banner loves Nat *because* she can control the Hulk. The most likely back story is that given Natashas history of spycraft and psychological warfare, she suggested a hypnotic trigger to Banner, and that brought them together, not the other way around.

Comment: I think it was more of a nod to "Beauty tames the beast". In the comics, Hulk has always reacted similarly to Betty Ross - her presence soothes his anger & calms him down.

Comment: the stock phrase, even used over telecom, makes me lean a bit more towards Lego's answer; that has to be at least part of it.

Comment: I'd add that Hulk is more likely to react negatively to someone he deems a physical threat or someone that can take a beating. Natasha, being a woman and without any extra protection, is less likely to set him off.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe it is Love at play here.

It looks more like an elaborate mechanism devised by the Avengers to help Banner revert back to himself after a "Code Green" is over.

This is evident from 2 things:

1. The Avengers instruct Natasha that it's time for "The Lullaby".
2. The Lullaby always starts with the exact same line, exact same hand gestures.

> "Hey big guy..... Sun's getting real low."
>   
>   This is similar to some [anger-mangement strategies](http://www.apa.org/helpcenter/controlling-anger.aspx) used by psychiatrists. 
>   The aforementioned link mentions:
>
> "Slowly repeat a calming word or phrase, such as "relax" or "take it
>   easy." Keep repeating it to yourself while breathing deeply."

So, in summary, it's a psychiatric hack designed over time by Dr. Banner himself with Natasha's help.

Answer (score 2):

**The scenes you mention appear to be a system worked out between Banner and Natasha, perhaps a post-hypnotic method of calming The Hulk when needed.**

Overall, this was most likely just a nod to the "Beauty tames the beast" scenario. In the comics & various animated representations of The Hulk, Bruce Banner's best friend/girlfriend/wife is Betty Ross - his Lois Lane, his Iris West, his "one true love". It is a common trope in the Hulk stories that even a rampaging Hulk can be instantly calmed by the presence of Betty:

[image: Ultimate Avengers - Hulk and Betty]

The scene with Natasha would seem to be an obvious transfer of this, only using Natasha instead of Betty Ross. This scenario was also presented in Ang Lee's [**Hulk**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(film)) (2003):

**UPDATE:** Having now seen the movie, it does appear that

> the specific phrase "The sun is getting low", followed by a touch on the hand and then arm, is some sort of post-hypnotic suggestion that calms The Hulk and causes him to revert back to Banner. Since Natasha is the only one who can do this, it would appear to be a system worked out in advance between her and Bruce Banner.

Comment: I think something similar (not exactly the same) happens in *The Incredible Hulk*... Hulk recognizes Betty and is nearly calmed down, until someone shoots him.